# Context mapping - relations

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices, bounded-contexts

Is it considered a bad idea that 2 bounded contexts can have upstream communication between them?

Example for, order BC will publish event, and inventory BC will subscribe for that event and in the same time, inventory BC can publish events and order BC will subscribe

Comment: Why not communicate directly from order BC to inventory BC and limiting the publish/subscribe mechanism for the feedback from inventory to order? This way, inventory isn't dependent on order.

Comment: @MarkusPscheidt if they communicate directly via rest calls, isn't that considered as anti-pattern and synchronous communication? Order should be able to complete it's job no matter if inventory is available or not, or they should be same MS

Comment: These concerns sound to me like rather technical issues. Even publish/subscribe doesn't guarantee that a published message is received. You could use a queue of events that need to be processed by Inventory, kept in the Order database until REST calls to Inventory were successful. Processing on the side of Inventory can be done asynchronously with feedback to Order via publish/subscribe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Nope this is *NOT* a bad idea, in fact this is a great idea, let me explain.**

First consider your bounded contexts, in reality they should know nothing about each other, even when multiple `Contexts` are working together to create a complete solution, all a context `knows` about is itself, its *OWN* concerns.

Take an `OnboardingContext` responsible for when a new employee starts at a company, here an `Employee` entity is added for the first time into the system. Here the employee has a Name, Phonenumber, Start date, Address, Marital Status and more.

Consider the `PayrollContext`, it too has an `Employee` entity but here all this entity has is an Id, a Salary, Start Date and End Date - here it doesn't care about the address, or marital status, it doesn't even necessarily care about the Name, becuase in *THIS* context name is not important, only the Salary, Start Date and End Date.

So if the two contexts, shouldn't know about each other, but maybe care about some information relating to both, how do we get the fact that a new `Employee` has started and needs to get paid?

**Domain Events**

Domain events are used with distributed systems. The model of course, will become more complex, but also more scalable. Domain Events are used in an [event driven architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_architecture)

**Heres how it might work**

1. A new employee starts and is added to the system in the `OnboardingContext`, everything is correct and the model is persisted successfully.
2. The `OnboardingContext` raises an event, the event is called `NewEmployeeEvent`

Thats it for the `OnboardingContext` as far as it is concerned it is done. It's handled the new employee, saved it, and raised a nifty system wide event to say that something (an event) has occured.

Now to the `PayrollContext`

1. The `PayrollContext` is interested in a couple of things, in particular it want's to know when a new emplyee starts.
2. It subscribes to the `NewEmployeeEvent` this event is of a common type, it doesn't know where the event comes from, in fact it could come from anywhere, but it is interested in a little bag of data, or inormation on that event.
3. When the event is raised this context `handles` that event, in this case grabbing pertinent info about the Salary and Employee Number, it persists this to it's own data store for use later during payroll.

Boom done.

Your system now listens to and responds to events, these flow throughout your system, in any direction, in all directions.

When something of interest happens and event is raised, anyone (context) interested in that event subscribes, handles and does what it want's with the data relating to that event.

**So how do you do this?**

There is lots of reading to do, just google DDD and Domain Events.

You will come across a lot of articles from Jimmy Bogard ([a better domain events pattern](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/05/13/a-better-domain-events-pattern/)) and Udi Dahan ([Domain Events Salvation](http://udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/)) on the subject

Take a look at [nservicebus](https://particular.net/nservicebus) (paid for) and [masstransit](http://masstransit-project.com/) (open source) they are fantastic out of the box eventing, and messaging systems.

Nservice bus has some great videos on the subject at https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/architecture/principles

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, this is a bad idea.**

Your design would result in a circular dependency between the two BCs. As in many other areas of software development, **circular dependencies are almost always a bad idea**.

If your use cases force you to do this, then you should reconsider your context map. Ask yourself the following questions:

- Are the two BCs really separate BCs, or should they rather be one?
- Or should a part of one of the BCs that lead to the circular dependency in fact be in a third BC?

Finding answers to these questions **in the context of your domain** will probably lead you to a cleaner design.

Comment: Let's say we have Orders BC and payment processing BC. When order is created, event is published. Event is then cached up and processed by payment processing micro-service / bounded context. If the processing was successful, that order somehow needs to be marked as completed in the first BC. You want to say that i should have third microservice/BC which will then store all orders with their statuses, such as order history bc?

Comment: This concrete example sounds more like a case for the "put everything in one BC" approach. But it REALLY depends on what your domain looks like, so I won't be able to give you the "right" answer.

Comment: When you integrate with another system, which requires you to receive data from them and send data to them, you have some sort of customer-supplier with two-way communication using events. I am always concerned that on something that Eric Evans would say "well, it depends", there will be many people saying _NO, don't do this_.

Comment: Circular dependencies are indeed undesirable, but the interaction here is asynchronous (via pub-sub). This kind of connector doesn't generate tight coupling. Publishers and subscribers don't know about each other. Therefore, this design is not problematic for the reason stated. In fact, Hohpe and Woolf in Enterprise Integration Patterns talk about this: Request-Reply pattern (aka sync-over-async). The roundtrip of events does not cause any runtime issue either: a BC main entail multiple components; one might contain logic to send events, another might be a listener to consume events.